# Convert HTML to plain text and keep basic formatting

Tags: python, html, templates

I am looking for a way to convert HTML formatted text to plain text while maintaining its basic structure, and perhaps be slightly tweaked, so:

```
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<ol>
  <li>List item 1.</li>
  <li>List item 2.</li>
</ol>
<p>This is an <a href="www.google.com">anchor</a>.</p>
```

Becomes:

> This is a paragraph.
>
> - List item 1.
> - List item 2.
>
> This is an anchor (www.google.com).

Any ideas on how to effectively achieve for a very large number of HTML-formatted templates?

- Note that the most important part outside of the structure is keeping the anchors.

Comment: You should consider using Markdown or another lightweight markup language

Comment: This is currently a non option. I don't have access to modifying these, but I need them in plain text. :/

Comment: With [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try) (Haskell), you can easily convert a HTML source to a markup language.

Comment: @nicolas Thanks, I was already look at working with Pandoc before Claude made his suggestion. Thanks too, I learned another use for MD today. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a text-based browser, such as lynx, and have it output to stdout. I'm not sure it will suit all your tweaking-needs, but it's a very quick and easy start

`lynx -crawl -dump http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279364/convert-html-to-plain-text-and-keep-basic-formatting`

(actually, I would expect your list to be

```
1. List item 1.
2. List item 2.
```

since it's an ordered list)

Edit: actually looked more into your actual use case, it works perfectly:

```
> echo '<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<ol>
  <li>List item 1.</li>
  <li>List item 2.</li>
</ol>
<p>This is an <a href="http://www.google.com">anchor</a>.</p>' | lynx -stdin -dump
```

becomes

```
   This is a paragraph.
    1. List item 1.
    2. List item 2.

   This is an [1]anchor.

References

   1. http://www.google.com/
```

Comment: This actually looks good, except for the missing anchors. Now I need to find if it is possible with lynx to append the anchor next to the anchored text in some way.

Comment: By the way, you are correct, that is an ordered list, but I wanted to highlight that it's not really important.

Comment: I just made an edit with an actual example, (it wants http:// in the link or else it assumes it's local), which does include the link. The `-crawl` parameter was hiding the links.